# PostgreSQL window function slowing query down 1000 times

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, window-functions

Suppose I have the following table of cafes & restaurants in the USA:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shops (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    name text NOT NULL,
    category text, -- Could be anything the owner wants (eg. cafe-bar, italian etc)
    services text[], -- Preselected for the owner to choose (eg. 'beverages', 'alcohol', 'snacks' etc)
    city text NOT NULL, -- Again, user specified (eg. Seattle)
    state text NOT NULL CHECK (state in ('NY', 'CA', 'AZ', 'WA',...),
    rating real CHECK (rating IS NULL OR rating BETWEEN 1 AND 10) -- Updated from external table
)
```

I need to select shops in the following way:

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS filter_results
FROM shops
WHERE state IN ('NY', 'CA')
    AND services && '{"snacks", "beverages"}'
ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 500 -- OFFSET can be anything >= 0, just specifying one as an example
```

I tested this in a similar schema and I got execution times of about **1300 ms** from a table of more than **a million records**.

When I removed the `COUNT(*) OVER() AS filter_results` from the query, it took only **about 1.2 ms** - over **a thousand times faster**.

Running the following query to get the count separately took **about 400 ms**:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM shops
WHERE state IN ('NY', 'CA')
    AND services && '{"snacks", "beverages"}'
```

I have the following **indexes**:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_shops_state ON shops (state);

CREATE INDEX idx_shops_services ON shops USING GIN (services);

CREATE INDEX idx_shops_rating ON shops (rating DESC NULLS LAST);
```

The fact that the query only takes **1.2 ms without the window function** means that **the indexes work just fine**.

The filter result **count is required for pagination**. I've thought about **precomputing** all the combinations, but they are just **too many**.

Is there any way to optimize the window function and get the filter result count in **less than 10 ms**? We are talking about a **million record table**.

Here's what I got by running `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` before the query **(LIMIT 200, NO OFFSET)**:

**WITH WINDOW FUNCTION:**

```sql
"Limit  (cost=0.43..3933.73 rows=200 width=736) (actual time=1593.568..1593.697 rows=200 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, name, category, services, city, state, rating, (count(*) OVER (?))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5 read=96961, temp read=2706 written=3003"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.43..749077.54 rows=38089 width=736) (actual time=1593.567..1593.688 rows=200 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, name, category, services, city, state, rating, (count(*) OVER (?))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5 read=96961, temp read=2706 written=3003"
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_shops_rating on public.shops  (cost=0.43..748601.43 rows=38089 width=728) (actual time=0.054..1473.201 rows=38327 loops=1)"
"              Output: id, name, category, services, city, state, rating"
"              Filter: ((shops.state = ANY ('{NY,CA}'::text[])) AND ('{snacks,beverages}'::text[] && shops.services))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1051796"
"              Buffers: shared hit=5 read=96961"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared read=1"
"Planning Time: 0.257 ms"
"Execution Time: 1596.514 ms"
```

**WITHOUT WINDOW FUNCTION:**

```sql
"Limit  (cost=0.43..3931.23 rows=200 width=728) (actual time=0.014..1.005 rows=200 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, name, category, services, city, state, rating"
"  Buffers: shared hit=405"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_shops_rating on public.shops  (cost=0.43..748601.43 rows=38089 width=728) (actual time=0.013..0.996 rows=200 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, name, category, services, city, state, rating"
"        Filter: ((shops.state = ANY ('{NY,CA}'::text[])) AND ('{snacks,beverages}'::text[] && shops.services))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 979"
"        Buffers: shared hit=405"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1"
"Planning Time: 0.230 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.026 ms"
```

After experimenting for a while, I realized that with a an offset of 50 or more the execution time falls from **1250 ms** to **about 70 ms**. Maybe this can help, I don't know...

Comment: does execution plan show any thing interesting? paste the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` for your first query here as well

Comment: I just did and updated the content, thanks.

Comment: well, execution plan shows WindowAgg only took 120 ms , while the index scan took more than 1 second. so problem is not the aggregation function directly, maybe paste the execution plan for query without aggregation for comparison

Comment: I pasted it, thanks.

Comment: The statement without count(*) over ()  you paste does not include ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 100 OFFSET 500.  How does it run with that?

Comment: Which one do you mean? Are you talking about the 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' results?